# Unable to create Docker image for rga.open R script

Tags: r, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics

I am working on scheduling R jobs using Docker. I am using package `skardhamar/rga` to pull the reports from GA. I am not very familiar with Docker thus I am using package `o2r-project/containerit` to create the Dockerfile.

My aim is to pull reports from GA (standard) daily and thus want to schedule the script on Google Cloud using Docker. For this I am following this article

https://code.markedmondson.me/4-ways-schedule-r-scripts-on-google-cloud-platform/

However, when I am trying to create the docker file, I get the below error

```
dockerfile <- dockerfile("DockerTest.R", copy = "script_dir", soft = TRUE)
INFO [2020-02-05 10:22:22] Processing R script file 'DockerTest.R' locally.
INFO [2020-02-05 10:22:22] Creating an R session with the following expressions:
source(file = "DockerTest.R", echo = TRUE)
Error: <callr_status_error: callr subprocess failed: object 'redirect.uri' not found>
-->
<callr_remote_error in .rga.authenticate(client.id = client.id, client.secret = client.secret,  ...:
 object 'redirect.uri' not found>
 in process 9800
See `.Last.error.trace` for a stack trace.
```

The R Script that I am using is as below:

```
library(rga)
library(bigrquery)
bq_token()
rga.open(instance = "ga", where="~/ga.rga")

demoScheduleAPI <- function(){
  search_perf <- ga$getData(xxxxx, batch = TRUE, walk = TRUE, 
                          start.date = "2020-01-15",
                          end.date = "2020-01-16",
                          metrics = "ga:searchUniques",
                          dimensions="ga:date,ga:hour,ga:searchKeyword, ga:searchCategory ,ga:dimension6,ga:dimension10")
  project <- "bidone-data"
  insert_upload_job(project, "GA_Export_Prod_DataSet", "Test_Table", search_perf)
}
```

I understand that the rga would redirect me to obtain an auth token, however I have explicitly asked to use saved token, so I am not sure why I am getting this error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does the section on "authentication and authorisation", particularly the part on non-interactive session tokens, from the `bigrquery` docs help? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bigrquery/versions/1.2.0

Comment: @meenaparam it is not the big query which is the issue here, it is the rga package that I am using to pull reports from GA. My limitation is that I am working on standard GA and I need the unsampled report. I could not find any package in python that could do the trick